How can I extend the lightning datatable with custom type that has an edit template?
I have created a custom LWC that extends the lightning datatable, and defined a custom type inside. I want this custom type to have an edit template so that when editing the cell, it would show a checkbox and it would just display a text when not on edit mode.
What it is currently doing, is that, when I edit the cell, the checkbox appears. But when I tick, untick it, or even clicking outside the input, nothing happens and it just stays in edit mode.
Here's my custom datatable LWC code:
datatableExtended/datatableExtended.js
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import customCheckboxTemplate from './customCheckboxTemplate.html';
import customCheckboxEditTemplate from './customCheckboxEditTemplate.html';

export default class DatatableWithCustomTypes extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        customCheckbox: {
            template: customCheckboxTemplate,
            editTemplate: customCheckboxEditTemplate,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes : ['label', 'value', 'context', 'fieldName']
        }
    };
}

datatableExtended/datatableExtended.html
<template></template>

datatableExtended/customCheckboxEditTemplate.html
<template>
    <c-custom-checkbox
        data-inputable="true"
        value={editedValue}
        label={typeAttributes.label}
        context={typeAttributes.context}>
    </c-custom-checkbox>
</template>

datatableExtended/customCheckboxTemplate.html
<template>
    <span lwc:if={typeAttributes.value}>Nominated</span>
    <span lwc:else>Not Nominated</span>
</template>

customCheckbox/customCheckbox.html
<template>
    <lightning-input type="checkbox" checked={value} onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
</template>

customCheckbox/customCheckbox.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class CustomCheckbox extends LightningElement {
    @api value;
    @api label;
    @api fieldName;
    @api context;

    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.target.checked;
        const checkboxChangeEvent = new CustomEvent('checkboxchange', {
            composed: true,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            detail: {
                data: {
                    context: this.context,
                    fieldName: this.fieldName,
                    value: this.value
                }
            }
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(checkboxChangeEvent);
    }
}

